# undefined method `include?' for a relationship model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, relationship

I am trying to filter out some objects in an array by using the include? method, but I keep running into this error `undefined method 'include?' for #<Trip:0xa01b7b0>`.

I basically have two models, eventdeal and trip. I created a 3rd relationship model, eventdealtrip, that ties the two models together.

trip.rb

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :eventdealtrips, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :eventdeals, :through => :eventdealtrips
end
```

eventdeal.rb

```
class Eventdeal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :eventdealtrips
  has_many :trips, :through => :eventdealtrips, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

eventdealtrip.rb

```
class Eventdealtrip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :eventdeal
  belongs_to :trip
end
```

eventdealtrips/new.html.erb

```
<% if !@trips.blank? %>
  <% @trips.each do |trip| %>
    <% if !trip.include?(@eventdeal) %>
       <!--Content-->
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Basically, I only want to display the trips that do NOT include the current eventdeal (which is defined in the controller).

Any insight as to why I'm getting the undefined method error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The include? method is usually for arrays, try this:

```
<% if !trip.eventdeals.include?(@eventdeal) %>
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot the eventdeals.

Answer (score 2):

are you sure `trip` is an array? have you tried `trip.inspect`?

I'm not sure what exactly your `@trips` is, but I guess it's an array of `Trip`s. You should post that too.

```
trip.eventdealtrips.include? @eventdealtrip
// or
trip != @eventdealtrip
```